# Applying conservation of energy to any system?

Tags: energy, work

How would the conservation of energy be applied in any system?
Can we always be certain that every system will always obey COE? How can we be certain without measuring the system? Input & Output? 
Shouldn't we analyze all the variables involved? And calculate all the Work done in the system?

Answer (score 1):

The conservation of energy is a consequence of [Noether's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) and time shift symmetry. If the action for a system is not changed by changing the time $t$ to $t + T$, for some arbitrary constant $T$, that means the system must conserve energy. So as long as we know this symmetry applies we can be sure that the system conserves energy.

This assumes we are sure our Lagrangian accurately describes the system. If we don't know the Lagrangian for the system then I guess we have to do the experiments.

Comment: How would a system be described perfectly by the Lagrangian mechanics? Conservation of energy is primarily a mathematical axiom, however, there are factors that cause conservation of energy to make sense observably, the force,the fields, the displacement, the velocity physical factors that are observable to show conservation of energy.